# Is it possible to generate a default value for a certain database column using hbm2ddl

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, hbm2ddl

Env: JPA 1, Hibernate 3.3.x, MySQL 5.x

We auto generate database schema using hbm2ddl export operation. Would it be possible to generate a default value for a certain @Entity member during SQL generation. (e.g. archive field in mytable entity class.

```
create table mytable (
...
'archive‘ tinyint(1) default ’0 ’,
...
)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197045/setting-default-values-for-columns-in-jpa

Comment: @donroby - thanks for the link, adding the default value in columnDefinition is not portable and hence wouldn't want to use that mechanism. Alternatively I could use a default value in the Entity model. Is there a different way to specify this?

Comment: I don't think there's a portable way to specify a default in the mapping.

It might be best to set a default value either in the field declaration or in your constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no portable way to do that and the `columnDefinition` "trick" is definitely not a good solution. Actually, setting defaults in the generated DDL is just not a good idea, this would require the provider to go back to the database to see the result after an insert<sup>1</sup>. Better default in your Java code.

<sup>1</sup> Just in case, note that you can tell Hibernate to do that using the [`@Generated`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2859) annotation.