# JPA Entity CreateTimestamp is null after persist

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity with the field called createTimestamp.  This is created by the database when it is inserted.  The getter looks like this:

```
@Column(name = "create_timestamp", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", insertable = false)
public ZonedDateTime getCreateTimestamp() {
    return createTimestamp;
}
```

However, when my service calls the dao (spring repository) to create the entity, the create timestamp is null.

My dao method to create:

```
@Override
public int insert(AntennaSpec antennaSpec) {
    super.save(antennaSpec);
    logger.info("Antenna Spec " + antennaSpec.getAntennaCode() + " created");
    return antennaSpec.getAntennaSpecId();
}
```

My REST resource class calls the service to create the entity by calling the create method.  The method returns the id of the newly created entity.  In the resource, I then call my service to return the entity passing the id and yet the create timestamp is null.  What i have done to get this to populate is in my resource, i've detached the entity and then fetch the entity again.  That works but I don't like exposing `detach` to my service or resource classes.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you post your table DDL? The `columnDefinition` is used when hibernate generates the database for you, if you use liquibase for instance the DDL must not necessary match.

Comment: Apologies.  I forgot to mention that hibernate is not set to generate the database for me.  Just to validate that the existing database works with my entities.

Answer (score 1):

This is another way for a create timestamp in spring:

```
@CreationTimestamp
@Column(name = "create_timestamp")
private Date createTimestamp;
```

Comment: instead of Date i use Java 8's `ZonedDateTime` which appears it does not work with `@CreationTimestamp`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might want to add the annotation `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)` to your column as discussed in the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14703697/how-can-i-use-db-side-default-value-while-use-hibernate-save).

Look [here](http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-save-persist-update-merge-saveorupdate) for additional information on how persist, save, update, merge and saveOrUpdate perform differently for different object states.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not using `java.util.Date` but instead `ZonedDateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

`columnDefinition` has only an effect if you let hibernate generate the database; otherwise it is just ignored. Just alter your column via your database migration tool to the desired state.

> columnDefinition
>
> (Optional) The SQL fragment that is used when generating the DDL for
>   the column.
>   [JPA JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#columnDefinition--)

Answer (score 0):

It is another solution ...!!!

```
@CreationTimestamp
private LocalDateTime createTime;


@UpdateTimestamp
private LocalDateTime updateTime;
```

Don't Forget the use.. !!

" **@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)** "

Use like this --

[It is just Entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFUUu.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;



@CreationTimestamp
@Column(name = "created_at", updatable = false)
private Date createAt;
```