# How to save DATE at the MySQL column

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am building simple REST with Spring Boot, MySQL, Hibernate.
Want to save current date (autogenerated) using Hibernate but everytime i test it in the PostMan i get Null

```
@Entity
@Table (name="purchase")
public class Purchase {
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@Column(name = "name")
private String name; 
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="createat")
private Date created;}
CREATE TABLE `purchase`.`purchase` (
`id` INT NOT NULL             AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`createat` DATE,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

I Need to save current date to my createat COLUMN

Comment: You can add a default value in Java with `private Date created = new Date();`, I'm not sure this is what you were asking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use DB side default value while use Hibernate save?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14703697/how-can-i-use-db-side-default-value-while-use-hibernate-save)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Hibernate you can just use @CreationTimestamp to insert default date.

```
@CreationTimestamp
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "create_date")
private Date createDate;
```

and @UpdateTimestamp to update the value if necessary

```
@UpdateTimestamp
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "modify_date")
private Date modifyDate;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that @CreationTimestamp was exactly what I needed