# Please explain about insertable=false and updatable=false in reference to the JPA @Column annotation

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, eclipselink

If a field is annotated `insertable=false, updatable=false`, doesn't it mean that you cannot insert value nor change the existing value? Why would you want to do that?

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="person", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Address> addresses;
}

@Entity
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ADDRESS_FK")
    @Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Person person;
}
```

Answer (score 162, accepted):

You would do that when the **responsibility** of creating/updating the referenced column's entity isn't in the *current* entity, but in *another* entity.

Comment: You are saying that with updatable=false on Person it will disable updating of Person.name when updating address (I disagree as this is the purpose of cascade). Also u are saying that @Column definition does something different when its foreign key (Person) and when it is not foreign key (as there is no referenced entity to disable updating). By reading javadoc for updatable I would say that it will just disable to change Person for given Address if it is once persisted. Can you explain please?

Comment: Isn't this sufficiently defined by the cascade options already? I saw this being used to not run into trouble by trying to write to a generated column. (e.g. a volume column `GENERATED ALWAYS AS (height * width * length) VIRTUAL`)

Answer (score 151):

Defining `insertable=false, updatable=false` is useful when you need to map a field more than once in an entity, typically:

- when using a composite key
- when using a [shared primary key](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Primary_Keys_through_OneToOne_and_ManyToOne_Relationships)
- when using [cascaded primary keys](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToOne#Target_Foreign_Keys.2C_Primary_Key_Join_Columns.2C_Cascade_Primary_Keys)

This is IMO not a semantical thing, but definitely a technical one.

Comment: I strongly believe that this answer is much better that the accepted one. The accepted answer conveys the feeling that insertable/updatable attribute has to do with the creation/update of the related entity, whereas the real intention behind these attributes is to prevent insertion/update of the column in the current entity. The creation/update of the related entity is tackled by the cascade attribute of the mapping annotation.

Answer (score 33):

I would like to add to the answers of *BalusC* and *Pascal Thivent* another common use of `insertable=false, updatable=false`:

Consider a column that is not an *id* but some kind of **sequence number**. The responsibility for calculating the sequence number may not necessarily belong to the application.

For example, sequence number starts with 1000 and should increment by one for each new entity. This is easily done, and very appropriately so, in the database, and in such cases these configurations makes sense.

Comment: sequences are supported by JPA as well, so you could define your sequence with JPA annotations, too.

Answer (score 24):

An other example would be on the "created_on" column where you want to let the database handle the date creation

Comment: Is Hibernate supposed to block updates based on an updatable=false annotation? In my JPA repository test a created_on column with this annotation accepts updates without complaint.

Comment: @chrisinmtown Eclipselink will not include the column in the sql at all. I expect it is the same with Hibernate

Comment: actually this is the response I came for

Answer (score 6):

I think it simply means:

> ##### `boolean insertable`
>
> (Optional) Whether the column is included in SQL INSERT statements generated by the persistence provider.

> ##### `boolean updatable`
>
> (Optional) Whether the column is included in SQL UPDATE statements generated by the persistence provider.

Reference: https://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/Column

Comment: The best answer tbh.

Answer (score 3):

According to Javax's persistence documentation:

[insertable](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#insertable--):

> `public abstract boolean insertable`
>
> (Optional) Whether the column is included in SQL INSERT statements generated by the persistence provider.

[updatable](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#updatable--):

> `public abstract boolean updatable`
>
> (Optional) Whether the column is included in SQL UPDATE statements generated by the persistence provider.

It would be best to understand from the official documentation.

Comment: It helped me understand why a column annotated with `@CreatedDate` and/or `@UpdateTimestamp` was not getting updated if it also has `@Column(...insertable=false, updatable=false)`. Thanks!

Comment: Useful for Generated Columns / Computed Columns / Virtual Columns.

Answer (score 2):

Another reason could be that your attribute is mapped to a column of a view (Example, your hibernate entity is the fusion of a table and a view). So it does not make sense that your column can be inserted (or updated).

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "THE_VIEW")
@SecondaryTable(name = "THE_TABLE", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "THE_ID"))
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "THE_ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "VIEW_COLUMN", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private String viewColumn

    @Column(name = "TABLE_COLUMN", table = "THE_TABLE")
    private String tableColumn;
```

(I don't talk about updatable views here)

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the previous answers, a common use of `insertable=false, updatable=false` is to save redundant database queries, thereby improving performance.

Imagine having a Client class, which has a Parent entity. If you just want to check if a Client has a Parent, you simply need to check for the presence of value in its `parent_id` column. There is no need to ask Hibernate to fetch the Parent entity, with possibly all of its other associations, leading to additional number of queries:

```
public class Client {
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Parent parent;

    @Column(name = "parent_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private UUID parentId;
}
```

With the setup above, the `parentId` field will simply fetch whatever value is stored in the `parent_id` column, which is solely edited/updated by the Parent entity.