# @JoinColumns - repeated column in mapping for entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I may just be misunderstanding how @JoinColumns work, but I'm getting an error when I reuse the name attribute. But doesn't the name attribute map to a database column? Shouldn't I be able to reuse it?

There error I'm getting:

```
Repeated column in mapping for entity: data.model.DP column: division
```

The code:

```
@Column(name = "division", nullable = false)
private String division;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "division_labeldefintion", referencedColumnName = "labeldefinition"),
    @JoinColumn(name = "division", referencedColumnName = "abbr")
})
private LabelFile divisionLabel;
```

What I'm trying to do is do a multi-column join from one table (which contains the `division` column, and join it with the `LabelFile` table.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to reuse a column in a mapping you should mark one as `insertable=false updatable=false`, for Hibernate to know which Java reference value is the relevant one.

More information on when to use those attributes is available in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805584/please-explain-about-insertable-false-updatable-false).

Comment: But what if I want to make both the columns insertable and updatable?

Answer (score 1):

When using the JoinColumn annotation you must be aware that depending on the type of association between two tables/entities the attributes "name" and "referencedColumnName" are changing the place where they referencing to.
Check the JPA API, or [look here](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/JoinColumn) for more detailed description.

In your case the "name" attribute of JoinColumn on "divisonLabel" property is referencing to the source table/entity. And "referencedColumnName" is referencing to the columns from LabelFile table/entity.
So, you are trying to have two "division" columns in the source table/entity.

To have the mapping work switch values for "name" and "referencedColumnName".

Comment: Won't switching them change which table I'm grabbing from?
I want to have a "division" column AND use "division" in my join and use it to match up to "abbr" which is also in the LabelFile.

Comment: It will, and that's the point. The way you wrote it now the JPA/Hibernate is trying to create two columns named "division"; one for plain text field that has nothing to do with any associations; the second to be used as part of composite key.
Annotation above LabelFile property is creating new fields/columns inside the current entity/table.
 
note: try not to think in form of columns&tables, JPA and ORM are there to hide the DB from you and make you work with objects instead.
 
disclaimer: I'm typing this without writing any code, so it might be that I'm overlooking something. hopefully not.