# How to properly set-up Spring Boot & Hibernate using InteliJ?

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, intellij-idea, spring-boot

As the title suggests I am building a web application using Spring Boot and Hibernate for my data access layer and the development is done on InteliJ IDEA 14.1.2.

**My Knowledge**

This is my first time using Spring Boot, Hibernate and InteliJ. I have built a few small apps to test Spring Boot and Hibernate, but the complexity difference between those and the one I am building now is a bit bigger.

**Environment**

Regarding my environment, in case it matters, I am running Windows 7 SP1 64bit, MySQL server 5.6.17, InteliJ 14.1.2 and Ubuntu Server 14.04 on a VirtualBox 4.3.26 VM hosting a Redis 3.0.1 server.

**Purpose**

The purpose of using the above technologies at this point in time is the storage and retrieval of different entities to a MySQL database (Redis is used only for session externalization and sharing among app instances). In other words, I am building my data access layer.

**Database**

My complete database schema can be found here:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49544122/so/DB.pdf

**Source**

My Spring Boot application is the following:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.EnableRedisHttpSession;
import se.domain.cvs.abstraction.dataaccess.AccountRepository;
import se.domain.cvs.domain.AccountEntity;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    AccountRepository repository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {     
        System.out.println("=======================================================");
        AccountEntity account = repository.findByEmail("r.franklin@companya.se");
        System.out.println("My name is " + account.getFirstName() + " " + account.getLastName());
        System.out.println("=======================================================");
    }
}
```

I am using CommandLineRunner interface just to test the bare data access layer without introducing REST endpoints yet.

My configuration is the following in YAML format:

```
...
# MySQL Database Configuration
spring.datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cvs
    username: cvs
    password: cvs
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa:
    database: MYSQL
    show-sql: true
    hibernate.ddl-auto: validate
    hibernate.naming-strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy
    properties.hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
...
```

The JPA entities are automatically generated with InteliJ and that is where the problems begin. Let's take for example the OrderEntity below (for the sake of brevity I omit some code):

```
...
@Entity
@Table(name = "order", schema = "", catalog = "cvs")
public class OrderEntity {
    ...
    private int invoiceId;
    ...
    private InvoiceEntity invoiceByInvoiceId;
    ...

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "InvoiceID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public int getInvoiceId() {
        return invoiceId;
    }

    public void setInvoiceId(int invoiceId) {
        this.invoiceId = invoiceId;
    }

    ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "InvoiceID", referencedColumnName = "InvoiceID", nullable = false)
    public InvoiceEntity getInvoiceByInvoiceId() {
        return invoiceByInvoiceId;
    }

    public void setInvoiceByInvoiceId(InvoiceEntity invoiceByInvoiceId) {
        this.invoiceByInvoiceId = invoiceByInvoiceId;
    }
    ...
}
```

When trying to run the Spring Boot application I get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: OrderEntity column: invoiceId (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

After doing a little bit of research, I guess the problem is that the invoiceID now has two ways to be set, one through the `setInvoiceID()` setter and one through the `InvoiceEntity` object itself that the OrderEntity relates to, which could lead to an inconsistent state. As another user here puts it,

> You would do that when the responsibility of creating/udpating the related entity in question isn't in the current entity.

*See related post here: [Please explain about: insertable=false, updatable=false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805584/please-explain-about-insertable-false-updatable-false)*

Setting the proposed values of the corresponding field (`insertable` and `updateable`) to false fixes the error.

My question here is why is this generated the wrong way? My change fixed the error, but I want to make sure that there is no errors in my SQL that lead InteliJ to generate this the wrong way. The complete SQL script can be found here http://pastebin.com/aDguqR1N.

Additionally, when generating the Entities, InteliJ requires a Hibernate config file which I guess Spring Boot generates on its own somewhere else (or uses Java based configuration). Whether I leave it there or delete it, it doesn't seem to affect the app at all. I guess the order taken by SB to read properties overrides it. Is it OK that I just remove it?

Thank you very much for your time and help in advance and sorry for this long post! :)

Comment: TL;DR. Try to focus one ONE question. Post the *relevant* code, and the SQL query generated by Hibernate. You should never have an entity containing the ID of another entity. You should have ManyToOne or OneToOne associations instead.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your comment! It seems to me that indeed the ID properties are not needed at all, but what I want to know is why they got generated in the first place in case it's my SQL problematic. I also removed the second part of the post as you suggested. Thanks again! :)

Comment: I don't know. I would never use a tool to autogenerate my entities. They're the heart and soul of the application, and I want to be in control.

Answer (score 0):

my advice is to let Spring/Hibernate let generate your db schema for you ( everything including foreign keys and constraints can be generated by Spring.

For me the folloeing approach worked:

in the parent entity(in my case the TblUser):

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity=TblTracks.class,fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="tbluser")
    private List<TblTracks> tbltracks= new ArrayList<TblTracks>();
```

where mappedBy points to the Tbluser Entity (private TblUser tbluser)  of the child Entity

and in the child entity (in my case TblTracks) like

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
     @JoinColumn(name="idTblUser",nullable=false)
    private TblUser tbluser;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reposnse! :) I guess I am going to try it like this at first!