# Field with @CreationTimestamp annotation is null while save on repository

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jersey

(1) Why is the "@CreationTimestamp" field updated to null for a "save" called on the repository with a null value for that field?
I expect that a field annotated with "@CreationTimestamp" is never updated and maintained only once at the time of creation. But it does not work that way in my current project.

(2) I had to include @Column(updatable =false) (in addition to @CreationTimestamp annotation). Why is this necessary?

Comment: Do you have public getter for `@CreationTimestamp` annotated field?

Comment: Yes, we had it but it didn't seem to help. Now we no longer use the @CreationTimeStamp annotation and we are sticking to @Column(updatable=false)

Comment: Strange. Here it works.

Answer (score 37):

It's 2020, hibernate-core-5.3.12, and still need to set updatable to false.

```
@CreationTimestamp      
@Column(updatable = false)
private LocalDateTime createdDate;
```

Update

I believe there will be no fix for this because this `CreationTimestamp` is from native hibernate package (`org.hibernate.annotations`), and I believe the efforts will be on the jpa abstraction (`org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedBy`)

Comment: This helped me :)

Comment: wow where can I find more about this issue or some more details on the fix? thanks! it worked

Comment: I don't know if there is some fix in progress. I believe there isn't because this CreationTimestamp is from native hibernate package (`org.hibernate.annotations`), and I believe they are focusing their efforts on their jpa abstraction (`org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedBy`). See https://springbootdev.com/2018/03/13/spring-data-jpa-auditing-with-createdby-createddate-lastmodifiedby-and-lastmodifieddate/

Comment: It's quite amazing that almost all tutorials fail to capture this detail.

Comment: It's 2022 and I still had to add this to overcome some random bug that happened when I added a column to the database table. Before this table change I made there were no problems at all with the `@CreationTimestamp` or `@Column` annotations. Hiberate v5.4. What a headache this was, thank you for saving my sanity.

Answer (score 3):

@CreationTimestamp is not JPA but just Hibernate.

To create a field automatically with the creation date you can define a property like that:

```
  @Column(name = "creation_date", updatable = false)
  @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  private Date creationDate = new Date();
```

Answer (score 3):

1) I faced the same issue on Spring Boot 2.1.2 which uses Hibernate 5.3.7.
I read [here](https://thoughts-on-java.org/persist-creation-update-timestamps-hibernate/) that `java.util.LocalDateTime` handling was introduced in Hibernate 5.2.3, before that version you had to use one of the following date types:

- java.util.Date
- java.util.Calendar
- java.sql.Date
- java.sql.Time
- java.sql.Timestamp

**But it still did not work for me...**

So I came up with `javax.persistence.PrePersist` annotation:

```
...

@Column(name = "created_at", updatable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date createdAt;

...

@PrePersist
public void prePersistCreatedAt() {
    this.createdAt = new java.util.Date();
}
```

2)
This post discusses that topic and gives decent explanation: [Please explain about insertable=false and updatable=false in reference to the JPA @Column annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805584/please-explain-about-insertable-false-and-updatable-false-in-reference-to-the-jp).

Also pay attention to the not accepted posts, especially:

*Defining insertable=false, updatable=false is useful when you need to map a field more than once in an entity...*