# Hibernate and MySQL: @CreationTimestamp annotated Date property throws ConstraintViolationException when saving new Entity

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I'm making a Spring MVC app with Hibernate and MySQL. I have a TIMESTAMP column in one of my MySQL tables defined like this `tstamp timestamp default current_timestamp`.
The entity for this table has a composite primary key which includes the tstamp column.

The Entity class part where I define the EmbeddedId:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="trustassessments")
public class TrustAssessment {

    @EmbeddedId
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private TrustAssessmentId id;
    ....
```

The Embeddable class where I define the timestamp:

```
@Embeddable
public class TrustAssessmentId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="deviceId")
    int deviceId;

    @Column(name="tmsId")
    int tmsId;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="tstamp")
    private Date tstamp;
    ....
```

I'm using Jackson, so I POST in json format and I have tried these two:

1.

```
{
    "id": {
        "deviceId": 21,
        "tmsId": "20"
    },
    "trustLevel": 0.4,
    "honesty": 0.6,
    "cooperativeness": 0.4,
    "communityInterest": 0.2
}
```

2.

```
{
    "id": {
        "deviceId": 21,
        "tmsId": "20",
        "tstamp": ""
    },
    "trustLevel": 0.4,
    "honesty": 0.6,
    "cooperativeness": 0.4,
    "communityInterest": 0.2
}
```

The stack trace:

> Nov 28, 2019 9:07:28 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
>   WARN: SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000
>   Nov 28, 2019 9:07:28 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
>   ERROR: Column 'tstamp' cannot be null
>   Nov 28, 2019 9:07:28 PM org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl mapManagedFlushFailure
>   ERROR: HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]
>   Nov 28, 2019 9:07:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
>   SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/tms-rest-again] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause
>   java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'tstamp' cannot be null
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:117)

Comment: What is the hibernate version and is the same error coming for both scenerios?

Comment: Try using `@Column(name= "tstamp", nullable = false, updatable = false)` if the error comes on using second post request

Comment: @monster The hibernate version is 5.1.0 and I get the same stack trace for both scenarios. Adding your suggestion to the code didn't fix the problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the `@CreationTimestamp` and wrote it like this:

```
@Column(name="tstamp", updatable=false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date tstamp = new Date();
```

Props to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38227203/field-with-creationtimestamp-annotation-is-null-while-save-on-repository) answer.

However, it would be nice if someone could explain how this works and why it didn't work with `@CreationTimestamp`.