# What is the best way to manage inherit class with JPA?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, h2

**Context**

I have a class `Oeuvre`, and two sub class `Livre` and `Magasine`. An `Auteur` is linked to a `Livre`.

So the class diagram looks like :

```
       Oeuvre
          |
     ____________
    |            |
Magasine        Livre____Auteur
```

**Entities**

```
@Entity
public class Oeuvre {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String idoeuvre;

    @NotNull
    private String titre;

    @NotNull
    private String ISBN;

    @ColumnDefault("CURRENT_DATE()")
    private LocalDate parution;

}

@Entity
public class Magasine extends Oeuvre {

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Type type;
}

@Entity
public class Livre extends Oeuvre {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idauteur")
    private Auteur auteur;    
}

@Entity
public class Auteur {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String idauteur;

    @NotNull
    private String nom;

    @NotNull
    private String prenom;
}
```

**H2 representation**

```
Oeuvre(idoeuvre, isbn, parution, titre, type, idauteur)
```

But with this representation I can have empty values. For example `idauteur` will be `null` if `Oeuvre` is a `Magasine`.

So, this representation is not better?

```
Oeuvre(idoeuvre, isbn, parution, titre)
Livre(idlivre, idauteur, idoeuvre)
Magasine(idmagasine, type, idoeuvre)
```

**SQL script**

With the current database scheme I can't create this constraint : `ALTER TABLE livre ADD FOREIGN KEY (idauteur) REFERENCES auteur(idauteur) ON UPDATE CASCADE`

**Conclusion**

Is it possible to represent it with JPA/H2?

Thanks for your answers.

**EDIT 1 : Question**

Is it possible to have this database scheme with JPA / H2?

```
Oeuvre(idoeuvre, isbn, parution, titre)
Livre(idlivre, idauteur, idoeuvre)
Magasine(idmagasine, type, idoeuvre)
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question description, are you planning to have a single table called `Oeuvre` or are you going to have two tables, one for `Livre` and another one for `Magasine`?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know what is the best way to do it, can you advise me?

Comment: If you don't want those `null` issues, and you want to define a constraint for `Livre`, then I think you answered your own question, and you want a separate table for `Livre` and `Magasine`.

Comment: I can't create three entity ? `Oeuvre`, `Livre` and `Magasine`? Because if I create only `Livre` and `Magasine` I can't create constraints as `ALTER TABLE exemplaire ADD FOREIGN KEY (idoeuvre) REFERENCES oeuvre(idoeuvre) ON UPDATE CASCADE` right? `Exemplaire` is an entity linked to `Oeuvre`

Comment: @g00glen00b I edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you described your entities, Hibernate will expect the following database structure:

```
oeuvre(idoeuvre, titre, isbn, parution)
magasine(idoeuvre, titre, isbn, parution, type)
livre(idoeuvre, titre, isbn, parution, idauteur)
```

This will lead to a lot of duplication, and is probably not what you want. Now, you did describe two possible solutions though, namely:

1. Defining one table called `oeuvre`, where each field is present, for example:

   ```
   oeuvre(idoeuvre, titre, isbn, parution, type, idauteur)
   ```
2. Definining separate tables for `livre` and `magasine`, for example:

   ```
   oeuvre(idoeuvre, titre, isbn, parution)
   magasine(idmagasine, idoeuvre, idauteur)
   livre(idlivre, idoeuvre, idauteur)
   ```

Now, as you did mention, the first solution doesn't allow you to define a constraint, while the second one does. Basically, that means you provided your own answer, if you need a constraint, then you'll have to differentiate between the different types, and then you'll have to go for the second approach.

You could then define the following constraints:

- Each `magasine.idoeuvre` and `livre.idoeuvre` should be unique (you could even use them as a primary key)
- `livre.idauteur` should be `not null`

However, in this case, you don't need any inheritance. Inheritance within Hibernate is usually only done if multiple tables have the same fields, while in this case you have three separate tables, and thus three separate entities, no inheritance involved:

```java
@Entity
public class Oeuvre {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String idoeuvre;

    @NotNull
    private String titre;

    @NotNull
    private String ISBN;

    @ColumnDefault("CURRENT_DATE()")
    private LocalDate parution;
}

@Entity
public class Magasine { // No extends
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String idmagasine;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idoeuvre")
    private Oeuvre oeuvre;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Type type;
}

@Entity
public class Livre { // No extends
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String idlivre;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idoeuvre")
    private Oeuvre oeuvre;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idauteur")
    private Auteur auteur;   
}
```

The only reason why you could use inheritance in this case is because both `Magasine` and `Livre` both have a similar `Oeuvre` mapping, in that case, you could change your code like this:

```java
@Entity
public class Oeuvre {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String idoeuvre;

    @NotNull
    private String titre;

    @NotNull
    private String ISBN;

    @ColumnDefault("CURRENT_DATE()")
    private LocalDate parution;
}

@MappedSuperclass // No @Entity
public class SpecificOeuvre {
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idoeuvre")
    private Oeuvre oeuvre;
}

@Entity
public class Magasine extends SpecificOeuvre {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String idmagasine;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Type type;
}

@Entity
public class Livre extends SpecificOeuvre {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String idlivre;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idauteur")
    private Auteur auteur;   
}
```

Both represent the same database structure, the only difference is that one of them has a separate class annotated with `@MappedSuperclass` that contains all re-usable information between `Magasine` and `Livre`, which in this case is only the mapping to `Oeuvre`.

If you want to know whether or not an `Oeuvre` is linked to a `Livre` or a `Magasine`, you can use bi-directional mapping, for example:

```java
@Entity
public class Oeuvre {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String idoeuvre;

    @NotNull
    private String titre;

    @NotNull
    private String ISBN;

    @ColumnDefault("CURRENT_DATE()")
    private LocalDate parution;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "oeuvre")
    private Livre livre;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "oeuvre")
    private Magasine magasine;
}
```

Now you can see if `oeuvre.getMagasine()` is given or `oeuvre.getLivre()` is given.

Comment: Thanks for this very clear answer. However, I have a question, with the second solution, I can't know, from an `Oeuvre` if it's an instance of `Livre` or `Magasine` because they are not extended from `Oeuvre`. Is there a solution for that using `@MappedSuperclass`? Or a sql request is needed?

Comment: @N.Lamblin You can use bi-directional mapping for that by using the `@OneToOne(mappedBy = "oeuvre")` annotation within `Oeuvre`. I've edited my answer with an example. Behind the screens this will execute the additional SQL request for you, or apply a join when possible.

Comment: Thanks :) The last thing I need is have to the same id in `oeuvre / livre` and `oeuvre / exemplaire`. Indeed, it is a bit stupid to have 2 differents id... To do that can I use constructor like `Livre(String idoeuvre, Auteur auteur) { this.idlivre = idoeuvre; ...}` ? Or definied `idoeuvre` as @id ?

Comment: @N.Lamblin That isn't as easy, each entity must have an `@Id` field, and if you don't want to lose the `@OneToOne` mapping to `Oeuvre`, you'll have to map `idoeuvre` twice. However, Hibernate won't allow you, unless you define one of them as `updatable = false` and `insertable = false`. You can read more about that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3807285

Comment: Ok so I will keep `idlivre` and `idoeuvre` and add `updatable = false, insertable = false` on `idoeuvre` even if I find that a bit dirty ahah. Thanks!