# Error map @OneToMany relationship with JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm currently having a problem with OneToMany/ManyToOne mapping in my database. I would like my Sale Item table to have @ManyToOne mappings to Sale table.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sale")
public class Sale implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3857608619547245492L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "company", nullable = false)
    private Long company;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sale", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<SaleItem> saleItems = new ArrayList<>();

    public Sale() {
    }

    public void addSaleItem(SaleItem saleItem) {
        saleItems.add(saleItem);
        saleItem.setSale(this);
    }

    //****************************Getters and Setters****************************

}



@Entity
@Table(name = "sale_item")
public class SaleItem implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1016354254590870341L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "company", nullable = false)
    private Long company;    

    @Column(name = "description", nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "amount", nullable = false)
    private Double amount;

    @Column(name = "price", nullable = false)
    private Double price;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Sale sale;

    public SaleItem() {

    }

    //****************************Getters and Setters****************************


    public void setSale(Sale sale) {
        this.sale = sale;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (!(o instanceof SaleItem))
            return false;
        return id != null && id.equals(((SaleItem) o).getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 31;
    }   

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SaleItem [id=" + id + ", company=" + company + ", product=" + product + ", created=" + created
                + ", updated=" + updated + ", description=" + description + ", amount=" + amount + ", price=" + price
                + ", discount=" + discount + ", user=" + user + ", unit=" + unit + ", sale=" + sale + "]";
    }


}

    //*********************** My Controller ***********************

    /**
     * Create Sale
     * 
     * @param sale
     * @param result
     * @return ResponseEntity<Response<SaleDto>>
     * @throws ParseException
     */
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Response<SaleDto>> create(@Valid @RequestBody SaleDto saleDto, BindingResult result)
            throws ParseException {

        log.info("Creating sale: {}", saleDto.toString());
        Response<SaleDto> response = new Response<SaleDto>();

        validateSale(saleDto, result);

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            log.error("Error - invalid information for Sale: {}", result.getAllErrors());
            result.getAllErrors().forEach(error -> response.getErrors().add(error.getDefaultMessage()));
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(response);
        }

        response.setData(this.convertSaleDto(this.nova(saleDto, result)));
        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }

    private Sale nova(SaleDto saleDto, BindingResult result) throws ParseException {
        SaleItem saleItem = new SaleItem();
        saleItem.setCompany(saleDto.getCompany());
        saleItem.setPrice(saleDto.getItems().get(0).getPrice());
        saleItem.setDescription(saleDto.getItems().get(0).getDescription());
        saleItem.setUnit(saleDto.getItems().get(0).getUnit());

        Sale sale = new Sale();
        sale.setCompany(saleDto.getCompany());
        sale.setUser(saleDto.getUser());
        sale.addSaleItem(saleItem);

        return this.saleService.persist(sale);
    }



    //**************************My Service**************

    /**
     * Persist a sale
     * 
     * @param Sale
     * @return Sale
     */
    Sale persist(Sale sale);



//******************My impl***********************
@Transactional
public Sale persist(Sale sale) {
    log.info("Persisting sale {}", sale);
    return this.saleRepository.save(sale);
}
```

But I think I did something wrong because I recevied error about id null :

> ```
> SLF4J: Failed toString() invocation on an object of type [com.pissolato.api.entitys.Sale]
> Reported exception:
> java.lang.StackOverflowError
>   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.StringBuilder.<init>(Unknown Source)
>   at com.pissolato.api.entitys.SaleItem.toString(SaleItem.java:189)
>   at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
>   at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
> 2019-12-27 02:46:40.041  INFO 2684 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.p.a.services.implementation.SaleImpl   : Persisting sale [FAILED
> ```
>
> toString()]
>       Hibernate: 
>           /* insert com.pissolato.api.entitys.Sale
>               */ insert 
>               into
>                   sale
>                   (company, created, description, discount, sub_value, type, updated, user, value) 
>               values
>                   (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/3805682/3519504

Comment: 1 - Transactional don't work on private method because it's a proxy
2 - Where are you invoking save using repository interface?
3 - Why did you add `insertable = false`?

Comment: A good read to `OneToMany and ManyToOne` uni directional and bidirectional. https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Answer (score 2):

You are using mappedby on Inverse side so you dont need join column on the owning side of the entity (saleItem). Your 'saleItem' entity should look like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sale_item")
public class SaleItem implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1016354254590870341L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "company", nullable = false)
    private Long company;



    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "amount", nullable = false)
    private Double amount;

    @Column(name = "price", nullable = false)
    private Double price;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Sale sale;

    public SaleItem() {

    }



    public void setSale(Sale sale) {
        this.sale = sale;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (!(o instanceof SaleItem))
            return false;
        return id != null && id.equals(((SaleItem) o).getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 31;
    }
}
```

Here is sample Service class that I wrote for the testing .

```
  @Service
public class SaleService {

    @Autowired
    SaleRepository saleRepo;

    @Transactional
    public void saveSales() {

        SaleItem saleItem = new SaleItem();
        saleItem.setCompany(12L);
        saleItem.setAmount(232.0);
        saleItem.setPrice(23232.0);

        Sale sale = new Sale();
        sale.setCompany(12L);
        \\ Utility class will update on either side of the entities
        sale.addSaleItem(saleItem);
        saleRepo.save(sale);

    } 

}
```

TRACE logging ouput .

```
2019-12-26 21:33:32.980 DEBUG 12024 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    insert 
    into
        sale
        (company, id) 
    values
        (?, ?)
2019-12-26 21:33:32.985 TRACE 12024 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [12]
2019-12-26 21:33:32.985 TRACE 12024 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [1]
2019-12-26 21:33:33.069 DEBUG 12024 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    insert 
    into
        sale_item
        (amount, company, description, price, sale_id, id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2019-12-26 21:33:33.070 TRACE 12024 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [DOUBLE] - [232.0]
2019-12-26 21:33:33.070 TRACE 12024 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [12]
2019-12-26 21:33:33.071 TRACE 12024 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
2019-12-26 21:33:33.071 TRACE 12024 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [4] as [DOUBLE] - [23232.0]
2019-12-26 21:33:33.071 TRACE 12024 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [5] as [BIGINT] - [1]
2019-12-26 21:33:33.071 TRACE 12024 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [6] as [BIGINT] - [2]
```

Comment: I did your suggestion but when I persist my entity, just Sale class is saving in database. I thought  when a entity (sale) is saved, automatically SaleItem would go save together.

Comment: I was able to save both the Sale and sale_item entity in one shot. I have updated my answer by adding the Service class and TRACE logging

Comment: I was trying use your suggestion but now I received error (I have update my post), if   I remove  toString()  just  Sale is save.

Comment: Are you calling the addSaveItem method on the Sale class ? can you post the code on how you are setting the values to Sale object ?

Comment: I have updated my post with all code and tks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

remove nullable = false it will not allow the field with null value to update  it will in executing sql query

```
@Column(name = "sale_id", nullable = false)
private Long saleId;
```

Comment: This field is null in my database so if I remove nullable in my entity this error keep going.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding targetEntity to @ManyToOne annotation properties.

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Sale.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "sale_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Sale sale;
```

Comment: I did your suggestion but unfortunately it didn't work!