# Why is Hibernate not updating the Foreign key column for OneToOne relation?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, one-to-one

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t1")
public class Object1 {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "f_id")
  private Long id;

  @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},mappedBy = "object1")
  private Object2 object2;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "t2")
public class Object2 {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "f_id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "f_id",name = "f_integration_id",insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private Object1 object1;
}
```

The table **t1** has a column **f_id** which is it's primary key. The table **t2** has a column **f_integration_id** which references to the *f_id* column in the table **t1**.

Now when I try to save the **Object1** it is creating 2 rows in both tables **t1** & **t2**. But the foreign key column in table **t2** is still **NULL** . Can someone please tell why is this happening ? While it is working like a charm for OneToMany relation.

Comment: You should provide entities persistence code.

Comment: Hey @alexvaluiskyi There is not much persistance code. I am extending JPARepository and not Entity Manager. So the persistence code is just ```repository.saveAndFlush(object1)```

Comment: I mean service method where you create entity and save it to database. You have to assign both side objects relations

Comment: I do have bidirectional mapping defined in both Object1 and Object2 if u check in the snippet i provided.

Comment: You should set both side relations: `object1.setObject2(object2); object2.setObject1(object1);` before persisting

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @alexvaluiskyi . It worked!

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is in the below line. Your setting updatable and insertable to false. So it wont insert or update.You can refer this one [Please explain about insertable=false and updatable=false in reference to the JPA @Column annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805584/please-explain-about-insertable-false-and-updatable-false-in-reference-to-the-jp)

```
@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "f_id",name = "f_integration_id",insertable = false, updatable = false)
```