# One To Many Unidirectional association insert query getting failed

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, h2

I am having `User` and `Address` entity with `one-to-many` Unidirectional relationship.
When I am trying to insert `User` with `Address` details, it is getting failed with exception **"Referential integrity constraint violation"** , as I checked `Address` is not having inserted `userId` it has 0
I am not getting what is wrong with this.

My User entity:

```
        @Entity 
        @Table(name = "users")
        public class User{
        
            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
            @Column(name = "ID")
            private long id;
            
            @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true,cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
            @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
            private List<Address> address;
    // other table columns
        
         }
```

My Address entity:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "address")
    public class Address{
        
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "ID")
        private long id;
        
        @Column(name = "USER_ID")
        private long userId;
    //other table columns
    }
```

my controller:

```
    @PostMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> saveUser(@RequestBody UserRequestDTO userRequestDTO){
            try {
                if (userRequestDTO != null) {
                    return new ResponseEntity<>(userService.saveUser(userRequestDTO), HttpStatus.CREATED);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

My Service layer:

```
    @Override
        public UserDTO saveUser(UserRequestDTO userDto) {
            User obj = modelMapper.map(userDto, User.class);
            System.out.println(obj.toString());
            obj = userRepository.save(obj);
            return modelMapper.map(obj, UserDTO.class);
        }
```

Here is my UserRequestDTO in this I have all property

```
    public class UserRequestDTO {
    
        private long id;
        private long clientId;
        private String clientName;
        private String email;
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private String employeeNo;
        private String designation; 
        private String status;
        private String phoneNumber;
        private String employeeType;
        private String reportingTo;
        private String department;
        private String division;
        private String password;
        private String gender;  
        private String bloodGroup;
        private String maritalStatus;
        private String spouseName;
        private String noOfChildren;
        private Date dateOfBirth;
        private Date hiredDate;
        private LocalDate createdDate;
        private String createdBy;
        private LocalDate updatedDate;
        private String updatedBy;
        private List<Address> address;
    }
```

Checked many online tutorials but not able to get the root cause
Error message from console:

```
    User(id=0, clientId=1, email=user@gmail.com, firstName=user 10, lastName=K, password=password@123, employeeNo=EH5213, phoneNumber=9999999990, status=A, designation=Developer, employeeType=FullTime, reportingTo=Roshan, department=Information Technology, division=division, locationId=null, gender=null, bloodGroup=null, maritalStatus=null, spouseName=null, noOfChildren=null, dateOfBirth=null, hiredDate=null, createdDate=2022-03-25, createdBy=admin, updatedDate=2022-03-25, updatedBy=admin, organization=null, address=[Address(id=0, clientId=1, userId=0, address1=add1Sample, address2=add2Sample, state=sample, addressType=P, country=sample, city=sample, zipCode=000002, primaryPhone=1111111111, secondaryPhone=2222222222, active=true, createdDate=2022-03-25, createdBy=admin, updatedDate=2022-03-25, updatedBy=admin), Address(id=0, clientId=1, userId=0, address1=sample2, address2=add2sample2 , state=sample2, addressType=T, country=sample2, city=sample2, zipCode=000008, primaryPhone=4444444444, secondaryPhone=666666666, active=true, createdDate=2022-03-25, createdBy=admin, updatedDate=2022-03-25, updatedBy=admin)], employeeGroups=null)
    Hibernate: insert into users (id, blood_group, client_id, created_by, created_date, date_of_birth, department, designation, division, email, employee_no, employee_type, first_name, gender, hired_date, last_name, location_id, marital_status, no_of_children, organization_id, password, phone_number, reporting_to, spouse_name, status, updated_by, updated_date) values (default, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    Hibernate: insert into address (id, active, address_line_1, address_line_2, address_type, city, client_id, country, created_by, created_date, primary_phone, secondary_phone, state, updated_by, updated_date, user_id, zip_code) values (default, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    [2m2022-03-30 12:41:25.689[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m13308[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8085-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m SQL Error: 23506, SQLState: 23506
    [2m2022-03-30 12:41:25.702[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m13308[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8085-exec-2][0;39m [36mo.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK6I66IJB8TWGCQTETL8EEEED6V: PUBLIC.ADDRESS FOREIGN KEY(USER_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.USERS(ID) (0)"; SQL statement:
    insert into address (id, active, address_line_1, address_line_2, address_type, city, client_id, country, created_by, created_date, primary_phone, secondary_phone, state, updated_by, updated_date, user_id, zip_code) values (default, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23506-200]
```

Comment: ok let me update it

Comment: My 5 cents - the address you are inserting with user doesn't exist. Check if the address, or the address list, contains valid, e.g. already existing in database, entity.

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev I did debug and when insert into address getting failed  then at that time User record is not available

Comment: Up to your log you are inserting user with id = 0 in the address. So insert user, obtain the new id, update address with this id and insert address. It's exactly the reverse of what I said, sorry.

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev any suggestion to fix this

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej Yes, I am using spring boot 2.6.4

Comment: @ngi, try to do it in two steps - first insert the user, obtain id, update the address' list in user, insert address. I had similar problem a month ago and we solved it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be fixed by some small changes at Entity level:
Change-1:
Add nullable=false at your User entity, something like this:

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "users")`
public class User{`
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;
        
    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true,cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false)
     private List<Address> address;
// other table columns
}
```

Change-2:
Add insertable = false and  updatable = false at your Address entity, something like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address{
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "USER_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private long userId;
//other table columns
}
```

**Use of nullable=false :** It applies the not null constraint to the particular database column

**To to know uses of insertable = false, updatable = false  please refer this** :[Please explain about insertable=false and updatable=false in reference to the JPA @Column annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805584/please-explain-about-insertable-false-and-updatable-false-in-reference-to-the-jp)

Comment: ok let me make the changes and try it

Comment: After making the changes It is working

Answer (score 1):

You have to insert `User` first then after insert `Address` means you have to get reference of `User` before inserting `Address`. But in `Unidirectional Mapping` you don't need to put code for insert `Address` because it automatically get reference from `User`. `DTO` is not required here.

Remove this column from `Address.java` because it is bad pratice to insert foreign key manually:

```
@Column(name = "USER_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private long userId;
```

Here down is modified code:

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<User> addUser(@RequestBody User user)
{
    userRepository.save(user);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

You don't want to make DTO here...