# Instant Timestamp not showing in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

I am using Instant in java to store timestamp in mysql database:

However when getting the data from database it shows null.

Here is my code snippet:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="trade_data")
public class TradeData {

@Column(name = "creationTimeStamp",insertable=false)
private Instant CreationTimeStamp;


@Column(name = "VersionTimeStamp", insertable=false)
private Instant VersionTimeStamp;
```

}

```
    public ResponseEntity<?> addTrade(TradeData trade) {

    boolean validDate = false, validTrn = false, validBuyerSeller = false, validPartyCparty = false;
    
    trade.setVersion(1);
    trade.setTradeRefNum(trade.getPartyCode(), trade.getTradeId());
    trade.setS_no(0L);
    trade.setTradeDate(new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    trade.setCreationTimeStamp(Instant.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MICROS));
    trade.setVersionTimeStamp(Instant.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MICROS));
```

}

Comment: What does `insertable=false` mean?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805584/please-explain-about-insertable-false-and-updatable-false-in-reference-to-the-jp

Comment: It is definitely *not* going to help you that your naming is wrong. Variable names begin lower case. If they don't it might well break reflection/serialization