# How to specify Double's precision on hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I try to create a table from hibernate annotations. I need to have a column of Double type, with the length specified like : (10,2).
So SQL syntax show like:

```
... DOUBLE(10,2) ....
```

I have tried to do that:

```
@Column(length = 10, precision = 2) ...
```

but when i look at my created table, it is not specified the length for Double column. Does hibernate has solution for that or is it necessary to alter table configuration by hand?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you want the Decimal data type. I think floats/doubles only have precision parameter.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The `length` element of the Column annotation *applies only if a string-valued column is used*. In your case, you should use the `precision` and the `scale` elements.

```
@Column(precision=10, scale=2)
```

Here is what the specification writes about them:

> - `int` - `precision` - (Optional) The precision for a decimal (exact
>     numeric) column. (Applies only if a
>     decimal column is used.)
> - `int` - `scale` - (Optional) The scale for a decimal (exact numeric)
>     column. (Applies only if a decimal
>     column is used.)

#### References

- JPA 1.0 Specification

  - Section 9.1.5 "Column Annotation"

Comment: Very good. It works with "BigDecimal" Java type. But with "Double" does not. I have changed only the type and now work:).

Comment: @artaxerxe Any idea how can it work for "java.lang.Double"? :)

Comment: @plutonium1991 if you need the precision, you probably need to use `BigDecimal` instead.. that's why they probably do not allow this annotation on Doubles.. explanation here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/3413493

Comment: @plutonium1991 yes, either add custom columnDefinition as was answered by Kris or see my answer for Hibernate.

Comment: The JavaDoc for `@Column` `precision` and `scale` says "Applies only if a decimal column is used." that's why it doesn't work for `DOUBLE` columns. For that you need `columnDefinition="DOUBLE(10,2)"`.

Answer (score 30):

```
@Column(name="Price", columnDefinition="Decimal(10,2) default '100.00'")
```

[Setting default values for columns in JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197045/setting-default-values-for-columns-in-jpa)

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `@Digits` from the hibernate validator API which implements the javax.validation Bean Validation standard

```
@Digits(integer = 10 /*precision*/, fraction = 2 /*scale*/)
```

From the Javadocs

> The annotated element must be a number within accepted range Supported
> types are:
>
> - BigDecimal
> - BigInteger
> - CharSequence
> - BigInteger
> - byte, short, int,
>   long, and their respective wrapper types
>
> null elements are considered valid

Comment: This can be useful, but does something different: this validates the value before the entity is persisted and throws an exception if the value is out of the specified range. It doesn't change the database column definition. For example, if your database is accessed by another application, it could still write values of out that range into the column.

Answer (score 5):

Use **@Type** (only in Hibernate):

```java
@Column(precision = 5, scale = 4)
@Type(type = "big_decimal")
private double similarity;
```

Will result in definition (PostgreSQL, Oracle):

```sql
similarity numeric(5, 4),
similarity number(5, 4)
```