# JPA @Size annotation for BigDecimal

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, bean-validation

How do I use the `@Size` annotation for MySQL `DECIMAL(x,y)` columns?

I'm using `BigDecimal`, but when I try to include the `@Size` `max` it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
@Size(max = 7,2)
@Column(name = "weight")
private BigDecimal weight;
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could use the Hibernate Validator directly, and annotate your field with [@Digits](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html_single/#table-spec-constraints) like so:

```
@Digits(integer=5, fraction=2)
@Column(name = "weight")
private BigDecimal weight;
```

Comment: Would it work with TopLink's `javax.persistence_1.0.0.0_1-0-2.jar` as well?

Comment: Validation is a separate API from JPA. So, there will be no error when you try to persist the entity through `persist()` for example, you have to do the validation yourself

Comment: How do I do the validation myself? Is there a link to Oracle's site where I could read more on that?

Comment: What I meant is that validation should be done before you try to save to the database, at the view layer. See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gircz.html if you are using JSF, or here if you are using Spring http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html

Comment: Java EE 7: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/bean-validation001.htm#GIRCZ

Looks like `@DecimalMax` is the annotation to use?

Answer (score 19):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078559/how-to-specify-doubles-precision-on-hibernate)

```
@Column(nullable= false, precision=7, scale=2)    // Creates the database field with this size.
@Digits(integer=9, fraction=2)                    // Validates data when used as a form
private BigDecimal myField;
```

Comment: I think it should be @Column(nullable= false, precision=9, scale=2)  and @Digits(integer=7, fraction=2)

Answer (score 8):

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "DECIMAL(7,2)")
```

If you're asking how you should validate, you should use the @Min and @Max annotations or the @DecimalMin and @DecimalMax annotations.

@Size is an annotation used to validate a property, not to define its column. @Size is typically used to assure that a string or a collection is of a certain size.

Comment: So how would I use `@Max` to validate a `BigDecimal` with `7,2`?

Comment: @Threat when you say 'validate a BigDecimal with 7,2' ... can you clarify that a bit? When I read that I assume you're speaking about a BigDecimal with a specific scale and precision, which is different from a min and max value.

Comment: In other words, my `BigDecimal` must conform to, for example, `9999999,99` maximum. The same way that MySQL would validate it as far as I understand.

Comment: @ThreaT, `DECIMAL(7,2)` means a total of 7 digits, 2 of which are after the decimal point. So the maximum value that it can hold is 99999,99

Comment: It is throwing me SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 22003, ERROR: numeric field overflow. source is BigDecimal field. I tried to put over @Column(columnDefinition = "DECIMAL(8,8)"), so there is something more I need to discover.