# Spring JPA: How to Model Percentage Value

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

For Spring JPA within Spring Boot:

Within an `@Entity` class:

An attribute will hold a percentage value with two digit precision (like: `1.45 %`, `-195.12 %`)

What is the least errorprone way to specify/model this?

Comment: You are probably looking for `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 4):

As [chrylis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1189885/chrylis) already commented you should use BigDecimal as type.
Further you can use the precision and scale attribute of the @Column annotation to define the percentage value.

```
@Column(precision = 5, scale = 4)
private BigDecimal percentage;
```

In this case the percentage value is represented by a number between 0 and 1 with a fraction of 4 digits. 1.45% would be then stored as 0.0145. If you want to store the value as 1.45 you can use `@Column(precision = 5, scale = 2)`
But of course this also depends on your datatype. For MS SQL e.g. this would be equivalent to decimal(5,4) (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762302/appropriate-datatype-for-holding-percent-values)).

You find more information in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078559/how-to-specify-doubles-precision-on-hibernate) as well as within [this page](http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/persistable-basic-types/).

Alternatively you can also use the Hibernate Validation using the @Digits annotation as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907923/jpa-size-annotation-for-bigdecimal).