# restrict length of number column using jpa

Tags: java, oracle, jpa

I would like to generate a column (`abc NUMBER(2)`) (at the moment) in oracle:

```
@Column(length = 2)
private Integer abc;
```

but still in Oracle, the column created is `abc NUMBER(10, 0)`.

<del>I tried `@Digits(integer=2, fraction=0)` but I think this would not work as the Java type is `Integer`.</del>

Java doc for [@Digit](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/Digits.html) says:

> The annotated element must be a number within accepted range Supported
>   types are:
>
> ```
> BigDecimal
> BigInteger
> String
> byte, short, int, long, and their respective wrapper types
> ```
>
> null elements are considered valid

but `@Digits(integer=2, fraction=0)` has no effect on the generated column.

I am looking for a generic solution which could also work on MySQL also.

Comment: The Digit annotation is only for validation of the data and requires validator implementations to throw an exception when the value doesn't match what is defined. It has little to do with JPA and nothing to do with DDL generation in the database. If you are after a specific type in the database, you must define it yourself using the columnDefinition. If it doesn't work on a different database platform, you are stuck - you will have to override it in an orm.xml with specifics for your database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the precision obtained by *java-sql* data type mapping

```
@Column
private Short weightedScore;
```

Give also a try to `BigDecimal` specifying `precision` and `scale`

```
@Column(precision = 2, scale = 0)
private BigDecimal weightedScore;
```

IMHO BigDecimal [`precision`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#precision()) maps quite well with Oracle `NUMBER(precision)`.

<s>Use the `precision` attribute, i.e.</s>

```
@Column(precision=2)
private Integer abc;
```

I'd expect it generates some DDL such as `NUMBER(2,0)`.

See [How to specify Double's precision on hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078559/how-to-specify-doubles-precision-on-hibernate)

Comment: but I think mysql does not have `NUMBER`. So, this may restrict for oracle only. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-types.html

Comment: No where in the question you mentioned `MySQL` . @MohammadFaisal

Comment: So maybe with `@Column(precision=2)`.
Answer updated

Comment: the precision attribute applies only if a decimal column is used. as mentioned in the link you have added in the answer.

Comment: But using `@Digits(integer=5,fraction=2)` works on `BigDecimal` and generated column is `NUMBER(7,2)`. I could consider `Short`. Do I need to change anything else?

Comment: @MohammadFaisal updated answer with some attempts with `Short` and `BigDecimal`. I didn't try them... maybe on the weekend