# [Spring Data JPA]: @Column(scale) parameter has no effect

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, double, precision

I have the following DAO that is supposed to model bank accounts.

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "ACCOUNT")
public class AccountDao {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
  private String id;

  @Column(name = "balance", scale = 2)
  private Double balance;

  @Column(name = "currency")
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private Currency currency;

  @Column(name = "created_at")
  private Date createdAt;

  // equals(), hashcode()
}
```

*(I am aware that for balances one ought to best use `BigDecimal` instead of `Float` or `Double`, and it's happening in the next iteration. This is not production - grade code by any means.)*

My repository for this DAO simply extends `JPARepository<AccountDao, String>`:

```java
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<AccountDao, String> {}
```

The relevant controller and service class methods are relatively straightforward:

Controller POST endpoint:

```java
 @PostMapping("/newaccount")
  public ResponseEntity<EntityModel<AccountDto>> postNewAccount(@RequestBody AccountDto accountDto) {
    accountService.storeAccount(accountDto);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(accountModelAssembler.toModel(accountDto));
  }
```

Service method `storeAccount()`:

```java
public void storeAccount(AccountDto accountDto) throws AccountAlreadyExistsException{
    Optional<AccountDao> accountDao = accountRepository.findById(accountDto.getId());
    if (accountDao.isEmpty()) {
      accountRepository.save(
          new AccountDao(
              accountDto.getId(), accountDto.getBalance(), accountDto.getCurrency(), new Date()));
    } else {
      throw new AccountAlreadyExistsException(accountDto.getId());
    }
  }
```

When I `POST` the following payload:

```json
{
    "id" : "acc2",
    "balance" : 1022.3678234,
    "currency" : "USD"
}
```

My database (MySQL Ver 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.2) persists the `Double` with all the decimal digits, ignoring the `scale = 2` option that I have provided to the `@Column` annotation.

```sql
mysql> select * from account where id = 'acc2';
+------+--------------+----------------------------+----------+
| id   | balance      | created_at                 | currency |
+------+--------------+----------------------------+----------+
| acc2 | 1022.3678234 | 2023-06-30 23:48:10.230000 | USD      |
+------+--------------+----------------------------+----------+
```

Why does this happen? What am I doing wrong here (besides not using `BigDecimal`; see above)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that actually my problem is most likely exactly that I don't use a `BigDecimal`. Based on the comments [in the accepted answer of this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078559/how-to-specify-doubles-precision-on-hibernate), the `scale` parameter of the `@Column` annotation will NOT work for `Double` fields, but it WILL work for `BigDecimal` fields.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the answer shown below

In this updated **AccountDao**, the balance field is now of type BigDecimal, and the `@Column` annotation includes `precision = 15` and `scale = 2`. The precision attribute represents the total number of digits to be stored, and the scale attribute represents the number of digits to the right of the decimal point.

Here is the AccountDao shown below

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "ACCOUNT")
public class AccountDao {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
  private String id;

  @Column(name = "balance", precision = 15, scale = 2)
  private BigDecimal balance;

  @Column(name = "currency")
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private Currency currency;

  @Column(name = "created_at")
  private Date createdAt;

  // equals(), hashcode()
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear on how this works, it is _theoretically_ possible that _really large_ numbers, i.e with more than 13 non-decimal digits, will be truncated or will overflow, correct?

Comment: @Jason Did you test it? Does it work?

Comment: Yes, I used only the `scale` parameter, and it persists as desired. Thanks.