# Hibernate default values

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Is there a way with hibernate to define default values for each field and for the sake of database size write null instead of these default values?

For inst. let's say the default value for String is "". I would like Hibernate to:

1. return "" for each field, that has NULL in database.
2. write NULL to database, when I try to write ""

Of course, I can write thousands of Getters and Setters, but can it be done automatically?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set default value in Hibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110266/how-to-set-default-value-in-hibernate)

Answer (score 6):

> If you want a real database default value, use columnDefinition -
>   @Column(name = “myColumn”, nullable = false, columnDefinition = “int
>   default 100"). Notice that the string in columnDefinition is database
>   dependent. Also if you choose this option, you have to use
>   dynamic-insert, so Hibernate doesn't include columns with null values
>   on insert. Otherwise talking about default is irrelevant.
>
> But if you don't want database default value, but simply a default
>   value in your Java code, just initialize your variable like that -
>   private Integer myColumn = 100;

Source:

[How to set default value in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110266/how-to-set-default-value-in-)

Of course, instead of using:

```
columnDefinition = “int default 100"
```

Try something like:

```
columnDefinition = “TEXT default `default_text`"
```

I'm not sure if that's syntaically correct, but check these out:

[Text Field using Hibernate Annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281188/text-field-using-hibernate-annotation)

[Set default values using hibernate annotations in MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070682/set-default-values-using-hibernate-annotations-in-mysql)

Comment: When you declare the attributes of your class, you can initialize your default values of respective attributes there. That should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it does not answer my question - I don't want to store the default values in the database, I want to store NULL, whenever the default value is involved. As I wrote: `I would like Hibernate to write NULL to database whenever I try to write ""`.

Comment: Have you tried using a validator?  Check this out:  http://blog.inflinx.com/2012/04/24/custom-jsr-303-constraints/

Answer (score 0):

You may implement such thing using field getters, Its simple and will serve the purpose.