# hibernate JPA: optional value generation

Tags: hibernate, jpa, sequence

Is it possible to set a filed in hibernate to have a value generated whenever it is null?

This is not the primary key but business key. Basically I have a container with a barcode field. If no barcode is assigned, generate it automatically (eg, prefix + sequence number).

Is that possible or do I need to create a custom method for accessing the next sequence value?

Comment: there is an option to give default value. something like default = '' Have used it for giving default date for one timestamp field.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this: [Hibernate JPA Sequence (non-Id)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277630/hibernate-jpa-sequence-non-id)
The idea is to create an entity for the generated value `BarCode` and then use it as a property of your main entity:

```
@Entity
public class BarCode{

    private static final String PREFIX = "PREFIX";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(...)
    private Long number;

    public String getBarCodeValue(){
        return PREFIX + getNumber();
    }
}

@Entity 
public class MyEntity {
    @Id ..
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(...)
    private BarCode barCode;

    public String getBarCodeValue(){
        return barCode.getBarCodeValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to generate always. The value can be supplied from the outside and generation is only required if it is not supplied.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the value for the barcode from the class itself.
Try something like this.

```
int sequencenumber = generateSequence();
String barcode = prefix + sequencenumber;
```

I haven't tried this out. So I am not sure if this will work. Do try it out.

Also check this out:
[Setting default values for columns in JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197045/setting-default-values-for-columns-in-jpa)