# Hibernate default value for @joincolumn

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using jpa/hibernate

Country.java

```
@Column(nullable = false, name = "REGION")
private String region;

@Id
@Column(nullable = false, name = "CODE")
private String Code;
```

User.java

```
@Column(nullable = false, name = "NAME")
private String name;

@NaturalId
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "COUNTRY")
private Country country;
```

Is there a way that I can set a default value for a @joinColumn in User.java for country column in hibernate?

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197045/setting-default-values-for-columns-in-jpa This maybe helpful to you in some way.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way that I can set a default value for a @joinColumn in User.java for country column in hibernate?

You could use [`columnDefinition` field in `@JoinColumn`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html#columnDefinition()) but this is database dependent which is not optimal.

The `@PrePersist` method might be a better solution:

```
public class User {
    ...
    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
       if (country == null) {
           country = new Country("US");
       }
    }
```

For other alternatives examples, see this answer: [Setting default values for columns in JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197045/setting-default-values-for-columns-in-jpa/375202)

Comment: In case Country is a column that currently doesn't exist in my DB. So I am not sure how will schema upgrade take place, considering it needs to be @naturalId and non nullable? I was asking this question since I need to update the existing records to default value of country column

Comment: You have a country id or something in your `User` table right @banes?  Or is it in a join table?  Regardless, the `@PrePersist` should work.