# Auto increment value and set start from 1 with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I need next functional. Below value

```
@Column(name = "incomeNumber", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int incomeNumber;
```

must start from 1 and be auto increment. How i can set this with hibernate ?

Answer (score 1):

you can do this. Also can delegate the increment to sequence in db

```
@GenericGenerator(name="incgenerator" , strategy="increment")
@GeneratedValue(generator="incgenerator")
@Column(name = "incomeNumber", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int incomeNumber;
```

Comment: don't work for me, value is 0 when create new Object

Answer (score 0):

Follow D. Pineda idea plus add an default value if you whant it start at 1; [Setting default values for columns in JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197045/setting-default-values-for-columns-in-jpa)