# Cant set the defaultvalue of a column in JPA

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

So i´ve searched around and found several answers on how to set a default value in JPA, for example: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197045/setting-default-values-for-columns-in-jpa/4167460)

But none of the answers are working for me.

I have the following entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Project {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  @Column(unique = true)
  private String name;

  private Integer budget;

  private String description;

  private Boolean isArchived;

  private LocalDate archivedDate;

  @NotNull
  @ManyToOne
  private Customer customer;
}
```

I would like to add a new field `date` of type `LocalDate`and set its default value to `LocalDate.now()` so every existing project inside the table gets `LocalDate.now` as its value for the `date` property.

So i tried doing it with the recommended way:

```
@Column(name="date")
private LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
```

But it does not work, the values are set to null in the database instead of to the default value i tried to define. If i check the columndefinition inside the database, theres also no defaultvalue set. If i add the new column manually with SQL and set a default value there, everythings working as expected, i just cant get it with JPA.

I also tried playing around with `columnDefinition` but couldnt get anything woring there aswell.

Answer (score 3):

you can try something like below in your entity

```
@Entity
public class MyJPAEntity {



@CreationTimestamp
private LocalDateTime createDateTime;

@UpdateTimestamp
private LocalDateTime updateDateTime;

}
```

---

you can also try

```
@Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
private LocalDateTime createDate;
```