# Not able to set default column value in JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

i'm trying to set default value for column and i have tried with below code in entity

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "integer default 1")
private Integer views;
```

now after running server still i could see views as null in sql. Any idea why not able to save default value.

Application.yml

```
hibernate:
  ddl-auto: create
```

its always create as still its in development stage

Comment: I guess, this would not update default values for existing records, but insert new records with this configuration given records are added via application. Or make sure that you have `property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"` set.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting default values for columns in JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197045/setting-default-values-for-columns-in-jpa)

Answer (score 1):

Please use the simple implementation in your code.

```
@Column("column name")
private Integer views = 1;
```

set Default value while create that variable. if you want to change **view** value by using setter method.

if your not set the value in the model means it take 1 as the default value.

Or if your want to use **columnDefinition**  please use like follow

```
@Column(name="view",columnDefinition = "integer default '1'")
```

Comment: Tried with  @Column(name="views",columnDefinition = "integer default '1'")
rebuilded, still i could see null in sql

Comment: use first approach @SameerShaik

Answer (score 1):

> you mean you look at the already existing rows in the table and you
>   expect them to have that value ?

if yes, then here is the problem.. you may need to run migration script to set the default value you want where its not set.

And for any future inserted rows I guess the default value should be set.

Comment: No not the existing rows, its new development

Comment: then, could you try just setting default value to the field like: private Integer views = 1, thats what basically the way i personally do it, you can also look at this here https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-default-column-values it explains the different ways to do it

Comment: if that didn't work either, i wonder the way you add it ? do you have a DTO there that you convert and probably it sets the value to null and overrides it.. probably idk..

Comment: yeah i do have a DTO but initially view value will be null so entity has to take care of default values

Comment: I see... do you have hibernate ddl update enabled, or its on prod / necessary to do the schema changes with migration scripts ? because in your case, you have to tell the DB itself to set the default values