# Default value in Spring Data projection with LEFT JOIN and WHERE clauses

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql, spring-data

I am trying to set a default value in Spring Data projection when value has not been found after JOIN and WHERE clause. Let's assume I have `Product` with optional `Status`. Statuses are translated into multiple `Languages` in order to meet i18n requirements. Below is simplified DB example diagram but sufficient enough to visualize my issue I guess.
[image: DB diagram]
And this is what I have tried so far:

```java
@Query(value =
        " SELECT p.id AS productId," +
        " p.barCode AS barCode," +
        " COALESCE(pd.productStatus, 'translation not found') AS productStatus " +
        " FROM ProductEntity p" +
        " LEFT JOIN p.productStatusEntities pd" +
        " LEFT JOIN pd.languageEntity l" +
        " WHERE (l IS NULL OR l.langName = :langName)" +
        " AND p.barCode IN (:barCodes)" +
        " ORDER BY pd.productStatus")
Collection<ProductProjection> findProductsByBarCodes(@Param("barCodes") Collection<String> barCodes,
                                                     @Param("langName") String langName);
```

**The problem is: when the translation is missing then entire row (product) is omitted (probably because of JOIN and WHERE clause).** All I want is to **return products with its status if translation exists, otherwise `translation not found` as status value**, example response:

| Product ID | Bar code | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345 | Some translated status 1 |
| 2 | 56789 | (null - status not set) |
| 3 | 54321 | Translation not found |

It's important to point out that I can't just return `null` status because it will be impossible to determine whether status has not been set yet or translation is missing. Furthermore, I can't fetch translations outside repository because I need to sort by statuses with pagination mechanism.

I have tried different query combinations and SO answers but with no success. Can anyone give me advice how can I solve my problem or point me out some reference? I am using JPQL with PostgreSQL but native SQL will be appreciated as well.

Comment: Does it helps you? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197045/setting-default-values-for-columns-in-jpa) or [this](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-default-column-values)

Comment: @GrigoriiRiabov thanks for link but unfortunately in my case problem is more related with relations (JOIN and WHERE clauses) but thank you.