# Setting Default Values for JPA Column Via Enviromental Variable (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity class where I want to set the default value for a column. I tried this:

```
@Column(name = "column", columnDefinition = "double")
@Value("#{new Double('${env.var:-0.25}')}")
@NonNull
private Double column;
```

Now, we cannot use @Value to set a value in the entity class. I saw some stackoverflow answers like this:

[Setting default values for columns in JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197045/setting-default-values-for-columns-in-jpa)

where you set a default in the column definition, but there is no way to default and inject a env value like @Value does. Is there anything I can do to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `@Value` works in spring managed bean, Declared only `@Entity` might not works what you want.

How about using like this?

```java
@Component
class SomeConfig {
  @Value("${SomeVal}")
  public String val;
}

@Entity
class YourEntity {
  @Column(name = "column", columnDefinition = "double")
  @NonNull
  private Double column = SomeConfig.val;
}
```

Although the constraints of the DB do not change, but programmatically, the default values can be determined through external settings!